MY NODE.JS SOLANA SNIPER BOT
please how do i fix this error
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
{"level":"error","message":"Error initializing bot: Non-base58 character"}

Please add your code, else we're just guessing.
